# Change the styling of a radiogroup in monotouch.dialog?

Tags: dialog, xamarin.ios, styles, monotouch.dialog, appearance

By subclassing the DialogViewController I've found my way to customize the styling of the DVC (setting background color etc.).

While that works as expected, I cannot find my way to customize the radiogroup (I want to style the screen with radioelements shown when tapping the radiogroup).

At first I figured I'd need to se the Appearance API, but that doesn't seem to effect MT.D screens? My second option was to subclass the RootElement, but that turned out to be rather hard because of a bunch of protected properties; I know I can make that work, but I'd think it could be done easier?

Thanks!

Comment: did you got answer to the question ? I also have the same issue to customise the styling when selecting the radio group